# MalformedPolicyDocumentException when creating AWS::KSM::Key

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a KSM key to use it in the S3 service, but I get the MalformedPolicyDocument exception. Here is the resource:

```
"CustomerMasterKey":{
  "Type" : "AWS::KMS::Key",
  "Condition" : "EnableEncryption",
  "Properties" : {
    "Description" : "Client Master Key used to encrypt data",
    "Enabled" : true,
    "EnableKeyRotation" : true,
    "KeyPolicy" :
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Id": {"Fn::Join": ["",["Key","Policy",{"Ref": "CustomerParam"}]]},
      "Statement":
      [{
      "Sid": "Allow access for Key Administrators",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": {"Fn::Join": ["",["arn:aws:iam::",{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},"moimeco"]]}
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Create*",
        "kms:Describe*",
        "kms:Enable*",
        "kms:List*",
        "kms:Put*",
        "kms:Update*",
        "kms:Revoke*",
        "kms:Disable*",
        "kms:Get*",
        "kms:Delete*",
        "kms:TagResource",
        "kms:UntagResource",
        "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
        "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
      "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS":
        [
          {"Fn::Join": ["",["arn:aws:iam::",{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"}, {"Ref": "CustomerParam"}]]},
          {"Fn::Join": ["",["arn:aws:iam::",{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},"userprod"]]}
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "kms:ViaService": "s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
      }]
    }
  }
},
```

I don't know where is the error, for me it is all good. Any idea please ?

> **::EDIT::**

This code is giving the same error:

```
"CustomerMasterKey":{
      "Type" : "AWS::KMS::Key",
      "Properties" : {
        "Description" : "A sample key",
        "KeyPolicy" : {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Id": {"Fn::Join": ["-",["Key","Policy",{"Ref": "CustomerParam"}]]},
          "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "AWS":  {"Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:iam::",{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},":root"]]}
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
          },
          {
            "Sid": "Allow administration of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": { "AWS": {"Fn::Join": ["",["arn:aws:iam::",{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},":user/","userprod"]]} },
            "Action": [
              "kms:Create*",
              "kms:Describe*",
              "kms:Enable*",
              "kms:List*",
              "kms:Put*",
              "kms:Update*",
              "kms:Revoke*",
              "kms:Disable*",
              "kms:Get*",
              "kms:Delete*",
              "kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion",
              "kms:CancelKeyDeletion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          },
          {
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": { "AWS": [{"Fn::Join": ["",["arn:aws:iam::",{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},":user/",{"Ref": "CustomerParam"}]]},
                                   {"Fn::Join": ["",["arn:aws:iam::",{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},":user/","moimeco"]]}]
                         },
            "Action": [
              "kms:Encrypt",
              "kms:Decrypt",
              "kms:ReEncrypt*",
              "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
              "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          },
          {
            "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "AWS": {"Fn::Join": ["",["arn:aws:iam::",{"Ref": "AWS::AccountId"},":user/",{"Ref": "CustomerParam"}]]}
            },
            "Action": [
              "kms:CreateGrant",
              "kms:ListGrants",
              "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {"Bool": {"kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"}}
          }
        ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined principals do not evaluate into Arns.

The first principal would evaluate to:

```
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11111111moimeco"
```

A valid ARN for a user would look like this:

```
"arn:aws:iam::1111111:user/username"
```

Additionally, you need to include the root user into your principals.

Otherwise, AWS wouldn't let you create the key at all. The reason behind this is described here:

[AWS Key policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html) under "Allows Access to the AWS Account and Enables IAM Policies"

Comment: I corrected the `Users Arn` and  I added the root in the principals and I still have the same error. Not really sure what else to do to correct the error. please help

Comment: I edited the question and put the new code which is giving the same error

Comment: Can you try setting both Principal Arns to {"AWS":"*"}, just to verifiy that there is no other issue with the template. I started from that point and incrementally added users to the list until I got the expected result working.

Comment: After setting all the principals to `{"AWS": "*"}` it worked perfectly. So the policy was not able to find the users. Something must be wrong with the `Fn::Join`

Comment: I got it working by editing one user Arn which I was going wrong  with

Comment: I have the exact same problem. As far as I can see, my root ARN constructed through Fn::Join is correct. Did you ever solve this properly?

Comment: AWS Key Policies doesn't say we need to include `root` in the principals. We can use the user/role as part of the Principal