# Receiving Error: error creating KMS Key: MalformedPolicyDocumentException:

Tags: devops, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms

I've currently got variables configured for the KMS policy statements in terraform. I'm trying to restrict access to the kms key from other users other than those described in the "Allow" policy. But when I run the terraform plan, I receive the following errors.

`Error: error creating KMS Key: MalformedPolicyDocumentException:`

Below is my test policy in my terraform module:

```
resource_policy_statements = {
rootPolicy = {
  actions   = ["kms:*"]
  effect    = "Allow"
  resources = ["*"]
  principals = {
    AWS = ["usera"]
  }
},
allowPolicy = {
  actions   = ["kms:CreateKey"]
  effect    = "Allow"
  resources = ["*"]
  principals = {
    AWS = ["userb"]
  }
},
denyPolicy = {
  actions   = ["kms:*"]
  effect    = "Deny"
  resources = ["*"]
  principals = {
    AWS = ["*"]
  }
  conditions = {
    StringNotLike = {
      AWS = [
        "usera",
        "userb"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

}

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since your terraform will attempt to apply, you should be able to copy the related policy from the apply log output and jump to the AWS Policy console, create a new policy and paste the malformed policy directly in the "edit json" editor. The policy editor will show red squigglys at the malformed parts.

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650980/malformedpolicydocumentexception-when-creating-awsksmkey

Comment: @RossBush thanks a lot. I found a link in the documentation explaining KMS key policies.